# Dart/Flutter How can I get access into an items in a list in a value of a map

Tags: flutter, api, dart

*I have this response from an API*

```
{
"error": "",
"success": {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "00005432",
            "channel": "B22",
            "case_status_id": "1",
            "case_type_id": "0",
            "provider_group_id": "1",
            "user_id": "78",
            "contact_id": null,
            "client_id": "23982",
            "subject": "parallala",
            "description": "",
            "latest_development": "",
            "priority": "medium",
            "caseArrivalDate": "2022-08-29",
            "arrivalDate": "2022-08-29",
            "dueDate": null,
            "closedOn": null,
            "statusComments": "dsdde 663171471 (ndnendn ))////#-#-&#+#+#+#+#(",
            "category": "edefrfr",
            "caseValue": "0.00",
            "internalReference": null,
            "externalizeLawyers": "no",
            "createdOn": "2022-08-29 10:59:46",
            "createdBy": "14",
            "modifiedOn": "2022-09-27 18:35:43",
            "requestedByName": null,
            "legal_case_stage_id": null,
            "caseClientPosition": null,
            "clientForeignName": null
        }
    ],
    "totalRows": "1122",
    "dbDriver": "MYSQL"
}
```

}

*I think its a Map(keys, values) and inside the key(success) we have another Map*

> How I can get access to a specific element?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that this value is assigned to a map type variable, I will name it response

so to access the id :

```
response["success"]["data"][0]["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should know how to access to Map
here Ex show you how  can get access to a specific element
myset  is Custom Map you provided it
((myset['success'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['data'] as List)
.where((e) => e["id"] == "00005432");

you will get list of Map And Filter List By specific  Id  Or Any attributes you need

after You understand it you can parse Map To Object And Access easyly To All attributes

hope this help you to get Started

[JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

Answer (score -1):

for ex. that is my data

```
const String _SexData = """[
  {
    "sex": "Seçiniz / Choice",
    "x": 1000
  },
  {
    "sex": "Male",
    "x": 1001
  },
  {
    "sex": "Female",
    "x": 1002    
  }
]""";
```

and I calling it;

```
DropdownButton<int>(
                      iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue,
                      dropdownColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 185, 242),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      value: sex?.x ?? 1000,
                      items: model1.sexs.map((a) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(a.sex,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          value: a.x,
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              sex = a;
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (s) {},
                    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).